# Mysql, php and html forms sync

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm pretty weak when it comes to forms, there seems to be something I am missing here, the mysql table is not being populated when a form is submitted and as far as information on the web goes, there is plenty on how to make forms, plenty on php, plenty on mysql but I am not finding anything that works that syncs the three, this is what I have:

Form (no worries, ill make the styles external as soon as I get the functionality down):

```
<div style="background-color:#424142; width:100%; margin-left:7%; margin-top:20px;">
    <form action="templates/tmpl_tmd022/scripts/post_subscription.php" method="post">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF;" colspan="2">Sign up now to recieve our free newsletter. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF;" width="30%">First name:</td>
                <td style="padding:5px; padding-left:0; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF;" width="70%"><input type="text" name="fname"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF;">Last name:</td>
                <td style="padding:5px; padding-left:0; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF;"><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF;">Email:</td>
                <td style="padding:5px; padding-left:0; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF;"><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="padding:3px; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000;"><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="color:000;"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    require "connect_to_mysql.php"; 

    $fname=($_POST['fname']); 
    $lname=($_POST['lname']); 
    $email=($_POST['email']); 

    $sql="INSERT INTO subscriptions (lname, fname, email) 
    VALUES ('$_POST[lname]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[email]')"; 

    mysql_close(); 

    header('Location: http://www.*websitehidden*.com/')
?>
```

The included connect_to_mysql.php file is the db name, db user, and db password, it is tested and functioning fine.

Does anyone have any idea as to what (probably stupid) mistake I am making?

Comment: mysql_query($sql) ? is missing ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not included the mysql_query() part that executes your query.

```
<?php
require "connect_to_mysql.php"; 

$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']); 
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']); 
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 

$sql="INSERT INTO subscriptions (lname, fname, email) 
VALUES ('$lname','$fname','$email')"; 
mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close(); 

header('Location: http://www.*websitehidden*.com/')
?>
```

Also the mysql_ function **should not be used** they are the old way of doing things and are not as fast and secure as the newer mysqli_ functions.

Comment: you should also escape the vars to using something like http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Well they should really be using prepared statements but yes i added that to the answer for reference.

Comment: this worked, dunno why this did and the one bellow didn't, but thank you. I'll take a look at the link by @PaulBain Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix your SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscriptions (lname, fname, email) 
        VALUES ('$lname','$fname','$email')"; 
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it didn't solve the problem, but I see what you mean by it.

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work, the post above said pretty much the same thing, and it worked, but thank you.